# Lucene .net search

Tags: lucene.net

**I have a lucene .net searcher with this configuration by a ,net app with aspnet core2, with RamDirectory i have the same problem.** the infomation is only for test porpouse.

Lucene configuration!!

```
public TextEngine(double bufferSizeMB)
{
    _analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
    _directory = FSDirectory.Open(@"d:\index");
    _writer = new IndexWriter(_directory, _analyzer, true, 
    IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
    _writer.SetRAMBufferSizeMB(bufferSizeMB);
   _searcher = new IndexSearcher(_directory);
}
```

write data on the directory
    public void Index(Publication publication,
                      string subType,
                      string province)
    {
      var document = new Document();
      document.Add(new Field(
                         "subType",
                         subType,
                         Field.Store.YES,
                         Field.Index.ANALYZED));

```
  document.Add(new Field(
                    "province",
                    province,
                    Field.Store.YES,
                    Field.Index.ANALYZED));

  document.Add(new Field(
                     "publicationId",
                     publication.Id.ToString(),
                     Field.Store.YES,
                     Field.Index.NO));

  _writer.AddDocument(document);
}
```

search index text on subtype field

```
public string[] SearchTopBy(string index, int top)
{
  var parser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "subType", _analyzer);
  var query = new TermQuery(new Term("subType", index));
  var documents = _searcher.Search(query, top);
  var response = new List<string>();
  foreach (var document in documents.ScoreDocs)
  {
    var subtype = _searcher.Doc(document.Doc).Get("subType");
    var vecinity = _searcher.Doc(document.Doc).Get("vecinity");
    response.Add(subtype + " " + vecinity);
  }

  return response.ToArray();
}
```

when I write a unit test like

```
var engine = new TextEngine(1024);
var publication = new Publication
{
  Id = 1,
  IndexedDescription = "Test publication"
};

engine.Index(publication,
        "plomero",
        "almagro");

publication.Id = 2;
publication.IndexedDescription = "test 2";
engine.Index(publication,
       "plomero",
       "villa del parque");

var result = engine.SearchTopBy("plomero", 2);
Assert.True(result.Length == 2);
```

I will expect 2 result items, but i got 0 items.
can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should close the writer after writing documents to the index.
This commits all changes to the index and closes all associated files.

```
_writer.AddDocument(document);

_writer.Close();
```

See [Apache documentation](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d2/d1d/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_index_1_1_index_writer.html).